# How to run multiple EXE's, Open File and XCOPY's in a Batch Script

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to create a batch script to install a particular program via SCCM (eventually).

Currently I'm just trying to get it to run on my own machine but running into to one or two problems.

The Installation as a manual process is a pain, needs to run 1 prerequisite EXE, then once finished run the main EXE.  The process should then wait for that to finish before running the program itself and to be left open for 30 seconds (roughly) then kill that task.  Lastly, I need to copy some config files over.

Typing individual lines manually works but struggling for an all in one solution.  I've tried using timeouts, PAUSE, && - all seems to be failing to sequence the tasks one after the other.

```
vstor_redist.exe /q /norestart 
&& APP.exe /Silent 
&& cd "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\APP" "Shortcut.lnk" 
&& taskkill /IM "APP.exe" /F 
&& xcopy "config.config" %AppData%\COFIG\*.* xcopy "config.xml" %AppData%\CONFIG\*.*
```

Comment: `&&` is for running commands in the same line, not for typing them on separate lines like that

Comment: Ah! That makes sense as to why that wasn't working then - thanks.

Comment: Any ideas on what I could use instead?

Comment: remove all the new lines. `vstor_redist.exe /q /norestart && APP.exe /Silent && cd "C:\ProgramData...`

Comment: The && function doesn't appear to be working.  I *instantly* get an error for path not found for the '&& cd "C:\ProgramData' part which is because the EXE's (obviously) are still running

Comment: obviously `cd "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\APP" "Shortcut.lnk"` doesn't work because you can't change to 2 folders at once

Comment: [`&&`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) lets the latter command execute only if the former was successful (hence its exit code is zero); usage: `command1 && command2` (in a single line)...

Comment: Thanks for that, the problem is I need it to wait longer than for exit code 0. In one line I'm separating the EXE's with && and also the last command in the same line to load my next batch file, it just does it all at the same time so instantly returns the error of not finding a file because it hasn't finished with the EXE's yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that I was able to achieve my goal by using the `Start` command with its `/Wait` option.

Example:

```
start /wait app.exe
start /wait app2.exe
```

And so on